# Android espresso test fails with "Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { (has extras) }"

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to launch an activity with an intent passed to it inside an espresso test. The activity requires some setup before starting the activity, so I wanted to use `ActivityScenario.launch<MyActivity>(intent)`

I'm getting the error `Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { (has extras) }`

I see that activity is inside the AndroidManifest.xml file (`<activity android:name=".MyActivity" />`)

```
package com.foobar.app

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class MyActivityTest {

    @Test
    fun seeIfLaunchingAssetDialogWorks() {
        var intent = Intent()
        intent.putExtra("something", "something")
        var scenario = ActivityScenario.launch<MyActivity>(intent)
        scenario.onActivity {
            Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.myFileList)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        }
    }

}
```

The error is:

```
W/Settings: Setting always_finish_activities has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
E/TestRunner: failed: seeIfLaunchingAssetDialogWorks(com.foobar.app.MyActivityTest)
    ----- begin exception -----
E/TestRunner: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { (has extras) }
        at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker.startActivity(InstrumentationActivityInvoker.java:387)
        at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker.startActivity(InstrumentationActivityInvoker.java:416)
        at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launchInternal(ActivityScenario.java:265)
        at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:226)
        at com.foobar.app.FileListActivityTest.seeIfLaunchingAssetDialogWorks(MyActivityTest.kt:61)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:154)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
        at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
    ----- end exception -----

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { (has extras) }
    at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker.startActivity(InstrumentationActivityInvoker.java:387)
    at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker.startActivity(InstrumentationActivityInvoker.java:416)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launchInternal(ActivityScenario.java:265)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:226)
    at com.foobar.app.MyActivityTest.seeIfLaunchingAssetDialogWorks(MyActivityTest.kt:61)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:154)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
```

My app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.foobar.app"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 44
        versionName "0.6.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    def material_version = '1.2.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.madgag:markdownj-core:0.4.1'
    implementation 'org.gitlab4j:gitlab4j-api:4.15.7'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.17.0-rc'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.31.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.matomo.sdk:tracker:4.1.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2+'

    implementation('org.testng:testng:6.9.6') {
        exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
        exclude group: 'aopalliance', module: 'aopalliance'
    }

    testImplementation ('junit:junit:4.13.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    // Optional -- Hamcrest library
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    // Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'

    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'

    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'

    def room_version = "2.2.6"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"

    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"

    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.4"

}
```

The top level android build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: It happened to me whenI forgot to declare the activity in the manifest. 
Do not forget add or check the path.

Answer (score -3):

The solution was to create the intent like this:

```
var intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), MyActivity::class.java)
```

Then it works.